# Are there good audio books that focus solely on mastering an Italian accent?

Tags: pronunciation, resources

Some audio books that help you reduce an unwanted accent for English speakers can run into several hours.  I can't find anything of similar rigor in Italian.  I have found nothing on audible.com.  I have found something that is almost 6 hours here
https://www.accenthelp.com/products/italian
But it is for those who want to speak English with an Italian accent, not for those who want to speak Italian with an Italian accent.

Comment: You could look into "Corsi di dizione", even if these are usually aimed more at Italian speakers that want to reduce their regional accents

Comment: It looks very good.  So far I've only been able to find products on their side for as low as 1000 euros, which is too much.  I'll keep looking though.

Comment: The first random hit on amazon is [this](https://www.amazon.it/Manuale-professionale-dizione-pronuncia-CD-ROM/dp/8820348063/ref=sr_1_2?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=Dizione&qid=1623864765&sr=8-2) for 23€. No ideas about the quality, or if it's the best price

Comment: I own this book: https://www.giunti.it/autori/ughetta-lanari-4089. Not bad, but I often find quite difficult to remember the rules explained on it.

Comment: @bobsmith76 - “products on their side”: what do you mean? Denis didn't refer to a specific brand or school. “Corso di dizione” is a generic term meaning more or less “enunciation course” (or whatever they say in English to mean teaching to speak with no accent, or with a chosen accent). They are not necessarily courses given by a school: they can be books, CDs, software etc.

Comment: @DaG, in that case I meant https://dizionedigitale.it/corso-di-dizione-online-gratis/

Comment: @bobsmith76: I see. It doesn't look especially remarkable.

Comment: By the way, you can download the audio of the book I linked in my previous comment here: https://www.giunti.it/catalogo/manuale-di-dizione-e-pronuncia-2-cd-audio-e-mp3-9788809874381.